# How to parse letter by letter and make a list with Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file I am attempting to parse. Fairly new to Python.
It contains an ID, a sequence, and frequency

```
SA1 GDNNN 12
SA2 TDGNNED 8
SA3 VGGNNN 3
```

Say the user wants to compare the frequency of the first two sequences. They would input the        ID number. I'm having trouble figuring out how I would parse with python to make a list like

GD this occurs once in the two so it = 12

DN this also occurs once =12

NN occurs 3 times = 12 + 12 + 8 =32

TD occurs once in the second sequence = 8

DG ""

NE ""

ED ""

What do you recommend to parse letter by letter? In a sequence GD, then DN, then NN (without repeating it in the list), TD.. Etc.?

I currently have:

```
    #Read File
def main():
 file = open("clonedata.txt", "r")

lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

class clone_data:
        def __init__(id, seq, freq):
    id.seq = seq
    id.freq = freq

    def myfunc(id)
        id = input ("Input ID number to see frequency: ")


    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().upper()
        line.find(id)

            #print('y')
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. At first you say "Say the user wants to **compare the frequency** of the first two sequences." But then you provide an example where you **sum** the frequencies of adjacent pairs in both sequences. Finally, you provide pseudocode for a function which finds **a single sequence**, rather than a pair of sequences which could be compared or summed. What is your actual task?

Comment: Not sure if this helps:

Scan text for input id
 If found make list of clone letters start first letter stop next letter, start last letter stop next letter 
 Compare and add the number of the 2 digits if found on first sequence then add the sequence frequency to the amount of times the 2 digits were found, if found on the second sequence add that frequency onto of the others, if no 2 digits were repeated print the frequency it was found on.

The frequency is part of a biology term, i'm attempting to calculate a frequency of clones.

Comment: Sorry, no. But if you could break that down a bit and just ask for help about a single bit of that algorithm which you are having trouble with, it would be helpful. Perhaps I touched on your need in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from the example, but it sounds like you're trying to look at each line in the file and determine if the ID is in a given line. If so, you want to add the number at the end of that line to the current count.

This can be done in Python with something like this:

```
def get_total_from_lines_for_id(id_string, lines):
    total = 0 #record the total at the end of each line
    
    #now loop over the lines searching for the ID string
    for line in lines:
        if id_string in line: #this will be true if the id_string is in the line and will only match once
            split_line = line.split(" ") #split the line at each space character into an array
            number_string = split_line[-1] #get the last item in the array, the number
            number_int = int(number_string) #make the string a number so we can add it
            total = total + number_int #increase the total       
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what part of that task seems difficult to you, in part because I'm not sure what exactly is the task you're trying to accomplish.

Unless you expect the datafile to be enormous, the simplest way to start would be to read it all into memory, recording the id, sequence and frequency in a dictionary indexed by id: [Note 1]

```
with open('clonedata.txt') as file:
    data = { id : (sequence, int(frequency))
             for id, sequence, frequency in (
                 line.split() for line in file)}
```

With the sample data provided, that gives you: (newlines added for legibility)

```
>>> data
{'SA1': ('GDNNN', 12),
 'SA2': ('TDGNNED', 8),
 'SA3': ('VGGNNN', 3)}
```

and you can get an individual sequence and frequency with something like:

```
seq, freq = data['SA2']
```

---

Apparently, you always want to count the number of digrams (instances of two consecutive letters) in a sequence of letters. You can do that easily with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): [Note 2]

```py
from collections import Counter
# ...
seq, freq = data['SA1']
Counter(zip(seq, seq[1:]))
```

which prints

```
Counter({('N', 'N'): 2, ('G', 'D'): 1, ('D', 'N'): 1})
```

It would probably be most convenient to make that into a function:

```py
def count(seq):
    return Counter(zip(seq, seq[1:]))
```

Also apparently, you actually want to multiply the counted frequency by the frequency extracted from the file. Unfortunately, `Counter` does not support multiplication (although you can, conveniently, add two `Counter`s to get the sum of frequencies for each key, so there's no obvious reason why they shouldn't support multiplication.) However, you can multiply the counts afterwards:

```py
def count_freq(seq, freq):
    retval = count(seq)
    for digram in retval:
        retval[digram] *= freq
    return retval
```

If you find tuples of pairs of letters annoying, you can easily turn them back into strings using `''.join()`.

---

#### Notes:

1. That code is completely devoid of error checking; it assumes that your data file is perfect, and will throw an exception for any line with two few elements, including blank lines. You could handle the blank lines by changing `for line in file` to `for line in file if line.strip()` or some other similar test, but a fully bullet-proof version would require more work.)
2. `zip(a, a[1:])` is the idiomatic way of making an iterator out of overlapping pairs of elements of a list. If you want non-overlapping pairs, you can use something very similar, using the same list iterator twice:

   ```py
   def pairwise(a):
       it = iter(a)
       return zip(it, it)
   ```

   (Or, javascript style:  `pairwise = lambda a: (lambda it:zip(it, it))(iter(a))`.)